# Dynamically change Barman Backup file. (Using date)

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-10, barman

I need to make the backup file(/folder) name form barman more specific.

Can I achieve that?

Specifically..
When I run `barman backup db`
I want the backup name is, either,

```
db_fullbckp_date
```

or when I run Incremental backup,

```
db_incrbckp_date
```

thanks before.

Comment: what's your approach? show some code and specify what's unclear please

Comment: @VaoTsun so when I `barman backup db` barman will start backup, and the output file id will be like  `20180221T105425`
what I want to achieve here is, when I start the backup command, the id will be `db_fullbckup_22022018`